# UTF-16 in Python taking 4 bytes

Tags: python-3.x, unicode

I am playing with Unicode encoding using Python-3 and noticed a behavior which I am not able to understand.

**Following cases work as expected :-**

```
x = "A"
fo = open("test.txt","w",encoding="utf_8")
fo.write(x)
fo.close()
```

> > xxd -b test.txt
> >     00000000: 01000001   (1 Byte as expected)

```
x = "A"
fo = open("test.txt","w",encoding="utf_16_le")
fo.write(x)
fo.close()
```

> > xxd -b test.txt
> >     00000000: 01000001 00000000  (2 Bytes as expected)

```
x = "A"
fo = open("test.txt","w",encoding="utf_16_be")
fo.write(x)
fo.close()
```

> > xxd -b test.txt
> >     00000000: 00000000 01000001   (2 Bytes as expected)

**Why 4 Bytes with utf_16 encoding? :-**

My understanding is that UTF-16 is a variable length character encoding that uses either 16-bit or 32-bit depending on the character. For the charcater `A`, it should use only 16-bits. Can someone please help me understand this behavior?

```
x = "A"
fo = open("test.txt","w",encoding="utf_16")
fo.write(x)
fo.close()
```

> > xxd -b test.txt
> >     00000000: 11111111 11111110 01000001 00000000

Comment: The BOM is *required* if writing without a manually specified endianness.

Comment: @usr2564301, Thank you. I thought, I'll get only downvotes but no explanation :)

Answer (score 3):

The first two bytes are the UTF 16 byte order marker (BOM).  See http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html